# Passing variables between functions

Tags: python-3.x

I've searched on this site in many places, but couldn't understand any of it, as when I tried to implement it into my code, it didn't work.

Here's the code in full.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def keepscore():
    score = 0
    cscore = 0
return score, cscore


def gamestart():
    print("""Starting in:
  _____             
 |___ /             
   |_ \             
  ___) |  _   _   _ 
 |____/  (_) (_) (_)

                """)
sleep(1)
print("""
  ____              
 |___ \             
   __) |            
  / __/   _   _   _ 
 |_____| (_) (_) (_)

                    """)
sleep(1)
print("""
  _             
 / |            
 | |            
 | |  _   _   _ 
 |_| (_) (_) (_)

            """)
sleep(1)
play()

def play():
    score,cscore = keepscore()
    rps = ["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    cpu = rps[randint(0,2)]
    ask = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors? ")
    if ask == "Rock":
        if cpu == "Rock":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Rock!")
        print("It's a tie! Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
    elif cpu == "Paper":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Paper!")
        print("You lose!")
        cscore += 1
        print("Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
    elif cpu == "Scissors":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Scissors!")
        print("You win!")
        score += 1
        print("Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
elif ask == "Paper":
    if cpu == "Rock":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Rock!")
        print("You lose!")
        cscore += 1
        print("Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
    elif cpu == "Paper":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Paper!")
        print("It's a tie! Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
    elif cpu == "Scissors":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Scissors!")
        print("You win!")
        score += 1
        print("Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
elif ask == "Scissors":
    if cpu == "Rock":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Rock!")
        print("You lose!")
        cscore += 1
        print("Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
    elif cpu == "Paper":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Paper!")
        print("You win!")
        score += 1
        print("Your score is: " + str(score) + ".  The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
    elif cpu == "Scissors":
        sleep(0.5)
        print("\nThe computer chose Scissors!")
        print("It's a tie! Your score is: " + str(score) + ". The computer's score is: " + str(cscore) + ".\n")
else:
    print("That wasn't a valid option. Please try again.\n")
return score,cscore

def best():
    bestof = input("Best of: 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5? ")
    if bestof == "1":
        for i in range(1):
            gamestart()
    elif bestof == "2":
        for i in range(2):
            gamestart()
    elif bestof == "3":
        for i in range(3):
            gamestart()
    elif bestof == "4":
        for i in range(4):
            gamestart()
    elif bestof == "5":
        for i in range(5):
            gamestart()
    elif int(bestof) >= 5:
        sleep(0.5)
        print("...")
        sleep(1)
        print("Really?... Fine.\n")
        sleep(2)
        for i in range(int(bestof)):
            gamestart()
    else:
        print("Defaulting to 3...")
        for i in range(3):
            gamestart()

keepscore()
best()
```

What I'm trying to do is make the score stay after each iteration of the loop, however it resets back to 0 every time.
I have tried multiple methods including while loops and globally set variables.

Comment: Please link to the questions that didn't make sense or didn't work in your code, I can find plenty of resources that explain how to change `global` variables in functions.

Comment: maybe see https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. As @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen said you can pass a `global` decoration, an example would look like this:

   ```
   var1 = 0
   def my_fun1():
       global var1 #the Global decoration
       var1 = int(input('Input a number: '))

   def my_fun2():
       if var1 % 2 == 0:
           print(var1, 'is an even number!')

   my_fun1()
   my_fun2()
   ```

   The only problem is as the Docs say:

   > Names listed in a global statement must not be defined as formal
   >   parameters or in a for loop control target, class definition, function
   >   definition, or import statement.
2. Or you could do it with *Argument*, this is the value that goes between the brackets at the end of the function (`my_fun()<--` those). An example would look like:

   ```
   var1 = int(input('Input a number: '))

   def my_fun1(var2):
       if var2 % 2 == 0:
           print(var2, 'is an even number!')

   my_fun1(var1)
   ```